# Rails LoadError for Models/Controllers with different namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces

I decided to do a bit of refactoring on my code since one of my project starts to get really big. I thus decided to namespace some models in quite independent modules, for clarity.

However, my controllers have an extra outer module since I have different subdomains or different kinds of controllers for all those models.

Therefore, I have a model `A::MyModel` in `app/models/a/my_model.rb`

and controllers `X::A::MyModelsController` and `Y::A::MyModelsController` in `app/controllers/x/a/my_models_controller.rb` and `app/controllers/y/a/my_models_controller.rb.

I happen to get, on some endpoints only, an exception `LoadError: Unable to autoload constant MyModel, expected [...]/app/models/a/my_model.rb to define it`. Exception is pretty clear except that it should be looking for `A::MyModel`.

It only happens on some of the endpoints, I even managed to make it work for an endpoint with AJAX, but not in HTML. However, it works properly with Rspecs as none of my tests fail.

I suspect this has something to do with Autoload as when it fails, it does not even get into the controller: There is no stack and no `Processed By xxx` in the logs.

I am using Ruby 2.4.2, Rails 5.2.0, and here is my `application.rb`

```
require_relative "boot"
require "rails"
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MonApp; end
class MonApp::Application < Rails::Application
    config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = true
    config.generators do |generate|
        generate.assets false
    end
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq

    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join("app", "models", "**", "*")]

    config.middleware.use I18n::JS::Middleware
    config.exceptions_app = self.routes
end
```

Surprisingly, it seems to fail when using Ajax with a `contentType: "application/json"`. Same endpoints without ajax or without this contentType seem to work.

My controller is

```
class X::A::MyModelsController
    def create; end
end
```

Has anyone some insights on this?
Thanks!

Comment: Which Rails Version are you using?

Comment: Can you post the content of you `application.rb`?

Comment: I use Ruby 2.4.2 and Rails 5.2.0. I added my `application.rb` in my original post

Comment: Do you have these classes defined as `class A::MyModel` or `module A; class MyModel`. You may think these mean the same thing but from a constant lookup perspective they do not. I would recommend the latter as it functions more naturally [Nice Article](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html)

Comment: I use the compact notation (the first one) since the indentation gets really annoying when one has already a few nested modules. I can try again with the latter but I think I already did and that it did not work.

Comment: @JrmKrb please do and report back as the error suggests `MyModel` in not defined in that file because you are actually defining `A::MyModel` which is not exactly the same thing. You could also reference the classes by their full name e.g. `A::MyModel` which would likely work as well.

Comment: It does not work with the other notation neither. I am not referencing anywhere to `MyModel`, Rails is failing, not my code, and Rails does not even get inside the controller

Comment: @JrmKrb you have to be referencing it somewhere otherwise it would not evaluate it at all. Can you post the code for the failing endpoint. In addition referencing `A::MyModel` as `MyModel` from inside `module X` will fail because it is defined in a completely different namespace where as `::A::MyModel` should work

Comment: It fails so with an empty action

Comment: It seems to happen only for some ajax endpoints, as some endpoints work in HTML but not in ajax, for some reason.

Comment: Surprisingly, it seems to fail when using Ajax with a `contentType: "application/json"`. Same endpoints without ajax or without this contentType seem to work.

Comment: then post one of the failing endpoints

Comment: It is empty. `def create;end` for instance

Comment: After a bit more investigation, it seems to be a `safe_constantize` from Rails that fails, in `actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb` . I guess Rails is trying to `safe_constantize` `"X::A::MyModel"` which ends up after fallbacks on trying to safe_constantize `"MyModel"` which does not work because it should look for `"A::MyModel"`